# How to sort an array of objects in the order of another array containing the unique values of a property present in each object?

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have have two arrays, I want to merge them into one object. I have given some examples of what I have and what I want to achieve. I tried `_.union` and few other underscore methods.

```
var original = [
  {
    Country: 'US',
    value: '10'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Turkey',
    value: '5'
  }
];

var newlist =["Afghanistan", "Antarctica","Turkey"]
```

The Results I want:

```
var results= [
  {
    Country: 'Afghanistan',
    value: '0'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Antarctica',
    value: '0'
  },
  {
    Country: 'Turkey',
    value: '5'
  }
];
```

The US would not appear in the final results because the newlist doesn't have US. So basically all the values from the new list would appear in the results with the values from the original list.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code?

Comment: tried _.union, but it attaches the last list to the first one. This is not what I want. I found that you could do .merge but underscore doesn't have merge.

Comment: if you would to merge both array where is the object with Country: 'US' in your expected output?

Comment: The US would not appear in the final resutls because the newlist doesn't have US. So basically all the values from the new list would appear in the results with the values from the original list.

Comment: Probably should add the above comment to the question - it's pretty vital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-Underscore solution, that [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)s the new array, returning the object from the original array if it can [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it, otherwise returning a new object:

```js
var original = [
  { Country: 'US', value: '10' },
  { Country: 'Turkey', value: '5' }
];

var newlist =["Afghanistan", "Antarctica","Turkey"]

var result = newlist.map(function(v) {
  return original.find(function(o) { return o.Country === v })
      || { Country: v, value: '0' }
})

console.log(result)
```

It's a one-liner with ES6 arrow functions:

```js
var original = [
  { Country: 'US', value: '10' },
  { Country: 'Turkey', value: '5' }
];

var newlist =["Afghanistan", "Antarctica","Turkey"]

var result = newlist.map(v => original.find(o => o.Country===v) || {Country:v, value:'0'})

console.log(result)
```